# how to compile a Golang project correctly with a package that has C code inside

Tags: c, go, compiler-errors

I started writing a project in Golang, but immediately ran into a problem. I need to connect from my code to the hardware, I have a driver and a vendor-provided wrapper for Golang. The description of the wrapper connection says that you need to put the code in the src directory of the project (I don't use such a directory, but I put the files in the directory./internal/fptr10 by package name and in my main.go it is successfully imported). I see the methods inside this package in the IDE GoLand, but when I try to compile the project (I call the very first function that should create an instance of the driver and is called New()) - I get the error: fptr10.New() undefined. There are two header files written in C in the wrapper directory and I understand that there is a problem with them, but I don't understand how to compile it correctly.

The entire project, together with the library itself, is available on https://github.com/Natrix31/KKTWatcher
P.S.: I work under Windows

I tried to compile the project from the IDE, and from the command line using go build and go install
But the result is the same. The program does not compile and gives the error: New() undefined

Comment: Do you have a C compiler installed and CGO enabled?

Comment: I didn't install it separately. I was sure it was bundled with the ide. CGO is enabled by default, if I understood the documentation correctly

Comment: I'm not familiar with GoLand, but I would be surprised if they distributed MinGW-W64 with the editor. Can you run `gcc --version` on the command line? If you don't have gcc installed, that is why no cgo files are being compiled.

Comment: No, no. You are absolutely right. there is no gcc in my system. Thanks for the comment. Now I will install everything and try to compile it.

Comment: Thank you very much. And I apologize for such a stupid question. I installed the compiler and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario where you can drop the C code inside the Go module just make sure you have the C compiler installed in your platform and make a reference with preamble comments.

`main.go`

```golang
/*
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include "calc.h"
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(C.add(1, 2))
}
```

`calc.c`:

```c
#include "calc.h"

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

`calc.h`:

```c
int add(int a, int b);
```

Go has CGO enabled by default so just build it:

```bash
go build -o main.out .
```